# Enabling Revenue Schedule for Defined Products

Tags: product, schedule, opp-lineitemschedule

I am trying to enable Revenue Schedules for only certain products in my organization. I have enabled Revenue Schedules from the Product Schedules Settings. I did not check to enable Schedules on all products so how do I control which products it can go on?

Currently, it throws the error: "Scheduling is not enabled for this type" when I am trying to set the default schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When all else fails, RTFM or "Google is your Best Friend". See [Add and Edit Product Schedules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_and_editing_default_schedules.htm&language=en_US) in Salesforce Help:

> 1. Review considerations and examples.
> 2. Enable the appropriate schedule types.
> 3. Select a product from the Products home page.
> 4. Click Edit.
> 5. Select the type of schedule to create: quantity, revenue, or both. Your  choices are limited by your Salesforce org’s schedule settings and the schedule types that are enabled for the product.
> 6. Set the schedule details. See Schedule Fields for descriptions.
> 7. Save your changes.
> 8. To establish a schedule on an opportunity product, see Establish Schedules for Products on Opportunities.
> 9. To edit a product schedule, click Edit on the product detail page.